# Bootstrap Modal form bugs out when trying to use keyboard on mobile device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

I have a 'get started' form on my new site. It utilizes bootstrap's modal. I've been seeing there are a lot of issues using modals on mobile devices. Here's mine:

When you click 'get started' the appropriate modal opens. However, upon trying to input stuff into the fields the keyboard pops up for a second, the screen shifts around sporadically, and the keyboard closes before you can use it. I'm accessing my site on an htc evo(droid).

www.mobilemogulsjax.com

The modals also don't scroll.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Im highly considering doing away with all modal forms until mobile devices catch up.

Comment: Works great on my iPad I send you a test message. Chef :)

Comment: Note that the non-Chrome Android "Browser" app isn't officially supported by Bootstrap, mostly because it's super-buggy; see http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-browsers